# Why lodash .isNumber function is more complicated than typeof value == 'number'

Tags: javascript, lodash

Lodash `isNumber` function has an extra condition to check if value is number. I'm not sure why is that required and in what case it is not enough to use just `typeof value == 'number'`

```
function isNumber(value) {
  return typeof value == 'number' ||
    (isObjectLike(value) && getTag(value) == '[object Number]')
}
```

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/aa1d7d870d9cf84842ee23ff485fd24abf0ed3d1/isNumber.js

Comment: Maybe because `typeof NaN` is "number" ..? Uhh, the function doesn't seem to detect `NaN` at all.

Comment: _.isNumber(NaN) returns true

Comment: Maybe if you set an objects prototype to Number.prototype

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your link:

> Checks if `value` is classified as a `Number` primitive **or object**.

```
var n = new Number(3);
console.log(typeof n); // "object"
console.log(_.isNumber(n)); // true
```

[MDN - Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number):

> The Number JavaScript object is a wrapper object allowing you to work with numerical values. A Number object is created using the Number() constructor. A primitive type object number is created using the Number() function.

Answer (score 7):

While the `Number()` function will create a number primitive, the `Number()` constructor will create a `Number` object:

```
typeof Number(0) // 'number'
typeof new Number(0) // 'object'
```

Lodash checks for both cases.

Comment: Which raises the question of why someone might want a number object to be treated the same as a number primitive. The primitive constructors (Number, String, Boolean) seem to be there to complete the ECMAScript model, they're not intended to be used as constructors. E.g. `var a = new Number(3); a === 3` returns `false`, which might be unexpected.

Comment: @RobG True enough. But any operation that gets the internal `[[NumberData]]` slot value will still work. `new Number(3) == 3 // true` and `new Number(3) + new Number(5) // 8`